# Create own exception for Procedure PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

Well I have this Table

```
   JOB_ID     JOB_TITLE                           MIN_SALARY MAX_SALARY
---------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ----------
AD_PRES    President                                20000      40000 
AD_VP      Administration Vice President            15000      30000 
SH_CLERK   Shipping Clerk                            2500       5500 
IT_PROG    Programmer                                4000      10000
```

Then I have this procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE upd_job (
 pjob_id jobs.job_id%type,
 pjob_title jobs.job_title%type
)AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE jobs SET job_title = pjob_title WHERE job_id = pjob_id;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something went wrong');
END;
```

When I call the procedure like this:

```
CALL upd_job('IT_PROG', 'WebMaster')
```

The `JOB_TITLE` at `JOB_ID 'IT_PROG'` should be updated to 'Webmaster'. This works fine so far. But when I call the procedure like this

```
CALL upd_job('IT_WEB', 'WebMaster')
```

there should be an exception printed 'Something went wrong' because the `JOB_ID` 'IT_WB' does not exist but instead of printing the exception message nothig gets printed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669169/create-own-exception-for-procedure-plsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this code won't return an error if such a job ID doesn't exist; it simply won't update any rows, so - check whether anything has been updated and then display a message.

Instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT` call (which will be used only if tool you use to run the procedure supports it), raise the error which will be viewable by any tool.

Something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE upd_job (
  2   pjob_id jobs.job_id%type,
  3   pjob_title jobs.job_title%type
  4  )
  5  AS
  6  BEGIN
  7    UPDATE jobs SET job_title = pjob_title WHERE job_id = pjob_id;
  8
  9    if sql%rowcount = 0 then
 10       raise_application_error(-20000, 'No such job ID');
 11    end if;
 12
 13  EXCEPTION
 14    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
 15      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid value');
 16    WHEN OTHERS THEN
 17      raise_application_Error(-20002, 'Something went wrong (' || sqlerrm ||')');
 18  END;
 19  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec upd_job('IT_PROG', 'Littlefoot');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec upd_job('IT_PROG', 'Littlefoot and Bigfoot');
BEGIN upd_job('IT_PROG', 'Littlefoot and Bigfoot'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: Something went wrong (ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."JOBS"."JOB_TITLE" (actual: 22, maximum: 10))
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.UPD_JOB", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1
    
    
SQL> exec upd_job('IT_WEB', 'Littlefoot');
BEGIN upd_job('IT_WEB', 'Littlefoot'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: Something went wrong (ORA-20000: No such job ID)
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.UPD_JOB", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: What does the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and the -20000

Comment: It ... well, raises the exception (as demonstrated). Oracle reserved error codes from -20000 to -20999 for us, developers.

Answer (score 0):

you're SQL will run ok, it just won't update any records as the WHERE clause will never evaluate to true. As it wont throw an error in the scenario you've given, it won't show the behaviour you were hoping for.

If you add a line like this directly after the update statement:

`i := SQL%rowcount`;

then you can add logic to write a message when i=0

Comment: May you want to show me in the code what I have to change to get the message

Comment: Why don't you do some research and try to write the code and then come back if you're still having issues? Not trying to be rude but you'll learn a lot more that way rather than just being given the answer by someone else